# How to implement Forward Propagation/Backpropagation using compute shaders properly?

Tags: c#, tensorflow, neural-network, backpropagation, compute-shader

So my understanding is that forward propagation and backpropagation are very linear.
So with forward propagation, you have to calculate the first layer before the 2nd and so on until you reach the last layer(the outputs).
Backpropagation is much the same but going from the last layer to first layer, so reversed. Instead of updating neuron values, your adjusting weights and bias though.

If you tried creating a compute shader using say ComputeSharp in c#(that's what I am most familiar with), it seems you would have to dispatch the shader for each layer one after the other. Backpropagation is even worse, you would have to dispatch the backpropagtion shaders for each layer, then run forward propagation shaders to update the outputs, then repeat until the error rates for the outputs are low enough. It would seem the buffer uploads required between each run and the dispatching would be too slow.

Based on my own testing, the cpu beats the gpu by a mile.
Even for a network with 10 hidden layers, 100 inputs, 1000 neurons per layer and 2 outputs
Thats a network with 9,102,000 total weights.

The issue is the buffer uploads required between dispatches. If there was a way to upload the entire network to the gpu and do forward propagation for one set of inputs in one shader, then do backpropagation for one set of inputs, then it may be faster than the cpu.

Any help or ideas on how that can be done using a basic fully connected neural network would be great. Also I am not using tensorflow, though information on how tensorflow does this using gpu compute shaders would be helpful.

Comment: What is the actual purpose? If the goal is a high performance neural net implementation you are using the wrong tool, and you should probably write it using tool as close to the metal as possible, i.e. CUDA, OpenCL, or whatever API is most current. If the goal is to use an AI, just use existing frameworks. If the goal is learning AI, writing for the CPU should be sufficient.

Comment: The purpose is mainly learning. So that's why even though I could just use tensorflow, I would rather build my own to really learn how its working.